# Stroustrup's Graph.h

Tags: c++, graph, header

I am working my way through "Programming Principles..." by Stroustrup. I am trying to get one simple window program compiled, and have had no luck on linux or windows.

Eventually, after multiple problems I am trying to include Graph.h that I got from his site and nothing else. My errors are as follows (and I have no idea what to do now since I assume his code is correct)

```
$ g++ window.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/ext/hash_map:60:0,
                 from /home/nathan/Documents/c++/std_lib_facilities.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/Window.h:12,
                 from window.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
In file included from window.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(Point, Point)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:203:43: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:203:55: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Circle::Circle(Point, int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:286:26: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:286:32: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘Point Graph_lib::Circle::center() const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:290:49: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘const int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:290:63: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘const int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘void Graph_lib::Circle::set_radius(int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:292:57: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:292:71: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’`enter code here`
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Ellipse::Ellipse(Point, int, int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:302:33: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:302:40: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘Point Graph_lib::Ellipse::center() const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:306:49: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘const int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:306:62: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘const int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘Point Graph_lib::Ellipse::focus1() const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:309:55: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:311:66: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator+’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘Point Graph_lib::Ellipse::focus2() const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:316:55: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:318:66: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘void Graph_lib::Ellipse::set_major(int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:322:56: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:322:70: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘void Graph_lib::Ellipse::set_minor(int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:324:56: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:324:69: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator-’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h: In member function ‘void Graph_lib::Image::set_mask(Point, int, int)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:372:65: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘x’ based on conversion to type ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/Graph.h:372:74: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘y’ based on conversion to type ‘int’
```

Don't know if it is a faux pas to paste all my code, but anyway.
I have looked everywhere and have been trying for two days. I am now reasonably frustrated. Please help.

Comment: You should definitely post _some_ code, as this question is currently unanswerable, but try to limit yourself to a small snippet which still gives these errors rather than posting _all_ your code.

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.5/` seems like a bad place to be putting these files - that's where the standard library headers live.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct `Point.h` being included (`Graph.h` depends on `Point.h`)?  Maybe some other `Point.h` file is being found by the compiler before the one from the "Principles" example is found.

```
g++ -M Window.cpp
```

might help you determine that.

---

I pulled down the whole example and found that I did have to fix two lines in `Graph.h` to get it to compile, but they had nothing to do with the lines you're getting errors on, `Point.h`, or the `Point` type.

On lines 140-142 of `Graph.h`, I had to change:

```
private:    // prevent copying
    Vector_ref(const Vector&);
    Vector_ref& operator=(const vector&);
```

to:

```
private:    // prevent copying
    Vector_ref(const Vector_ref&);
    Vector_ref& operator=(const Vector_ref&);
```

I assume you've already done this as the compiler is getting past those lines without complaint.  After this fix, `Window.cpp` compiles fine (but doesn't link as I haven't built the libraries the example depends on).

I did this using MinGW 4.5.1.

Comment: Sorry - I originally posted the wrong options for getting GCC to list the locations of included files. `-E -dM` isn't helpful for that; use `-M`.

Comment: Wow, courageous.  When you hear the thunder clap it is already too late.

Comment: Thanks! And such a speedy reply! This seems to have alleviated some errors, although I am getting that his classes don't have the members I am trying to use, so I will look into that now. Why does this have problems? Surely he tested it?